# Sublime Text 3 automatically close HTML Tags

Tags: sublime-text-3

I've recently started using Sublime Text 3 instead of my old usual editor, Brackets. When I'm writing HTML in Brackets, I would type: (`|` represents the cursor)

```
<div>|
```

And Brackets would automatically generate the closing tag, like so:

```
<div>|</div>
```

If I pressed Enter after that, it would open and auto-indent the tag:

```
<div>
    |
</div>
```

I've seen several other answers that describe using a keyboard shortcut. But is there a way to do it **completely automatically** in Sublime Text 3?

**Edit:** The ability to do the second half of what I am describing is not a built-in feature of Brackets, but rather a [plugin](https://github.com/bryanjhv/brackets-tab-tags/). Also, here is an example:

[image]

Comment: In my experience, it does not autocomplete as you asked for. But when you type say for example <title> blah blah blah then type "</" - it auto completes by adding "title>" - thus making it "</title>". Notepad++ does not even do that

Answer (score 13):

To get tag autocompletion (and a ton of other cool features), check out the [`Emmet`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet) plugin, formerly known as Zen Coding. For example, typing `div`<kbd>Tab</kbd> gives you

```html
<div>|</div>
```

and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> then gives you

```html
<div>
    |
</div>
```

Its [syntax](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/) is based on CSS selectors, so you can do quite complicated things quickly. `#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a{Item $}`<kbd>Tab</kbd> would give you:

[image: Emmet]

Comment: Agree. I believe Emmet also auto closes a tag when you have an open tag and type `</`

Comment: This is an amazing plugin. It makes writing HTML as easy as writing Slim Template. Now if only it could making reading it easier.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that I use that will auto-close tags like described above named [Auto Close](https://github.com/sh4nks/auto_close).

You can install it via Package Control by searching for "Auto Close".

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in windows and may people in several forums suggested me to remove and reinstall Sublime 3. But issue not resolved. I don't know the cause of issue. it seems some problem occurred with the packages installed or settings configured. I got resolved the issue in this way.

**In Windows 10**

go to C:\Users\ *YOUR_USER_NAME* \AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3

Remove folders and contents from that folder it will resolve this issue.

**In Linux**

Please reverse the process described in https://packagecontrol.io/installation

> There is some issue coursing with this is that all the installed
>   packages will get removed. You need to reinstall needful packages
>   again.

So please make sure to note down and reinstall all the plugins needed.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OPs install is not broken, he's asking for additional functionality.